# How to play large duration video files in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I am developing a video app. Some video files having a long (43 minuite) duration and some files are less than 10 min duration.

Apple suggested if video duration is more than 10 min they want me use Httplive streaming. I am placing video control in web view and am loading the URL.

If I used large video files in MP4 format, will I get any problems? And what video size do I need to use that both iPhone and iPad orientates.

Can you suggest me video size, duration, and formats. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple will reject any app that *doesn't* use HTTP Live Streaming for videos longer than 10 minutes. So if you're using the native video player then you'll have to encode your video files accordingly.

Comment: thanks for u  r replay .i am using Html5 in UIWebview for playing the video.when i  click the video it id directly playing the video .but is the video playing in native player or html5 does have any video player .please replay me .